# How can I solve this problem"The view 'Index' was not found"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

> InvalidOperationException: The view **'Index'** was not found. The
> following locations were searched: 
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml 
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

See this image:

[image]

I try this `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` in `cmd` to make sure that certificate not valid when run ASP.NET Core in browser, but the problem still happen.

Comment: Did you check that the `Index.cshtml` is really located under the `\Views\Home` folder in your project? What version of the ASP.NET Core are you using?

Comment: Yes, I did , 7.0.9

Comment: Can you share the folder structure of your source Code?

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
> following locations were searched.I have searched everywhere and have
> not been able to find the problem.

Actually,it would nicer, if you could have share your project design. Acoroding to your error message, which means compiler would be searching views folder two directory inside your project parent directory but in really that's obviously not there. In your scenario, home or shared directory doesn't have index view or you are not calling them accordingly in controller you can see below:

[image]

Consequently, you are getting this very exception which I have reproduced accordingly as following:

[image]

**Solution:**

Make sure, your views are available in Home or Shared folder or the folder you are referring to. You could resolve your exception by providing the correct path. You can use either of the following to get rid of your issue.

```cs
 return View("./Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Note: This ./ is meaning the compiler would search Views folder one directory down from the parent directory which is the correct location.

```cs
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Note: You can use the  [tilde ("~") operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-from-multiple-locations) in any path-related property in server controls which would search the path.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Directory browsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#directory-browsing) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-from-multiple-locations)